# Why can't you use XPathResult in an xsl stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, xslt

Here is a snippet of the xsl stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:dtv="urn:app-tools-detailview">
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="dtv" >
  <![CDATA[
    function selectSingleNode(context, pathExpression, namespace) 
    {
        if(!context)
        {
            throw new Error("selectSingleNode cannot have a null context");
        }
    
        var doc = (context.nodeType != 9 ? context.ownerDocument : context);
    
        if (typeof doc.evaluate !== 'undefined') 
        {
            var nsresolver = null;
            if (namespace instanceof Object) 
            {
                nsresolver = function(prefix) 
                {
                    return namespace[prefix];
                };
            }
            var result = doc.evaluate(pathExpression, context, nsresolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
            return (result !== null ? result.singleNodeValue : null);
        } 
    
        throw new Error("no XPath engine found");
    }
    
    function getNodeValue(szXpath, oNodeList) 
    {
      let szVal = "";
      if (oNodeList && oNodeList.length) 
        {         
        var oSrchNode = oNodeList[0];
        let oNode = selectSingleNode(oSrchNode.documentElement, szXpath);
                        
        if (oNode)
        {               
                if (oNode.nodeType == 1)                 
                    szVal = oNode.nodeValue;      
                else                    
                    szVal = oNode.text;       
        }                 
      }
      return (String(szVal));              
    }
  ]]>
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:param name="pPageKey"/>

... the rest doesn't really matter
```

I am trying to apply xsl in the following way (apologies for the VB.net, its a legacy app):

```
Dim xslFileName = Request("xslSrc")
Dim xslPath As String = Server.MapPath($"~/Include/xsl/{xslFileName}")

Dim proc = New XslCompiledTransform()

Using fs = New FileStream(xslPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Using xr = XmlReader.Create(fs)
        proc.Load(xr, New XsltSettings(True, True), New XmlUrlResolver())
    End Using
End Using

Using sr = New StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
    Using xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)
        Using sw = New StringWriter()
            proc.Transform(xr, Nothing, sw)
            Response.ContentType = "text/html"
            Response.Write(sw)
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

The xml I am applying it to doesn't really matter either because the error happens right after I try to load the stylesheet, and I get a LoadException stating:

> Variable 'XPathResult' has not been declared

How can I make the Xsl Processor aware of XPathResult?  It's a standard Web Api.

Comment: What are you trying to do, by the way? Dynamically evaluate an XPath expression given in the XML source document? If you can use an XSLT 3 processor, you could do this in pure XSLT without having to call an extension function. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath

Comment: Why should your server-side ASP.NET VB code running XslCompiledTransform have any knowledge of and access to browser-side, JS based APIs like XPathResult? You can write extension functions using C# and VB (as well, I think, never tried) to be used from XslCompiledTransform but you will need to use .NET framework APIs.

Comment: @MartinHonnen care to share what you would use instead of XPath?

Comment: @ConalTuohy I am remediating a legacy app that was written for IE.  No matter what I do I can't get the xlst to work in Edge/Chrome and the xsltprocessor in both browsers is pretty useless as far as errors are concerned (doesn't throw exceptions, doesn't have a collection of errors you can inspect, it just fails silently and returns null).  So to figure out why the xslt was failing I implemented it as a .NET webservice since at least you get feedback there when the transform fails.

Comment: @ConalTuohy The reason I'm using XPath is because the original code used MSXML and it had a 'selectNodes' function built into the ActiveX control for the DOM object.  Standard components don't have this so I had to write an equivalent function using XPath.

Comment: I didn't suggest not to use XPath, I just think it doesn't make sense to use .NET's `XslCompiledTransform` as the XSLT processor and expect any extension function to have access to some browser API. The .NET XPath data model/API is centered around XPathNavigator and XPathNodeIterator, and XPathNavigator has an `Evaluate` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.evaluate?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I must have been very tired last night not to think of this... but duh, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE is a constant.  All you have to do is type that into your javascript console in your browser debugger, and bam it spits out the value of the constant.

You can then simply use the numeric value as the parameter since the constant is not defined whatever API the .Net Jscript engine implements.

So:

```
doc.evaluate(pathExpression, context, nsresolver, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
```

Becomes:

```
doc.evaluate(pathExpression, context, nsresolver, 6, null);
```